# Convert UL to dropdown list not working

Tags: jquery, dropdown, list

I am running a plugin called Divi Staff to show the staff on the website. I don't like how the specialisms are displayed and wanted to convert them to a dropdown list. I have tried to get this to work and followed a whole bunch of similar questions on here and Stackoverflow, tried to implement what they suggested and I am getting nowhere fast.

I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JustUsAgency/m168eoLh/1/) with the list working correctly, but when I implement it on the testing site, it refuses to work. Can someone help me figure out why this script isn't firing on the site?

My testing server is http://testing.burton-sweet.co.uk/team/. Any tips gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CharlieJustUs  when you use Fiddle is automatically sets the $ variable for you.   When your script tries to run on your site,  that variable is not set, and it fails.

Try this please.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('ul.clearfix').each(function() {
            var $select = $('<select class="dropdown-toggle" />');
            $(this).find('a').each(function() {
                var $option = $('<option />');
                $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
                $select.append($option);
            });
            $(this).replaceWith($select);
        });
    });

    // This will grab the value the select is being set to and redirect to the link
    $('select.dropdown-toggle').on('change', function(){
       window.location.href = $( this ).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Warwick, when I implemented this it gave a jQuery is not defined error. If I'm following your code then you were defining the jQuery with the $ in the brackets, which would then mean jQuery should fire whenever the code has a $.

Comment: Could I remove that and just have jQuery(function() { ?

Comment: Managed to sort it out! Needed to enqueue jQuery with the script.

Comment: One thing that's still not working is making the list perform an action, which I think is due to the fact that the class attribute from the parent li is part of the scripting that's in place. Is there a way to take the li class and add it to the option we created above?

Comment: @CharlieJustUs I have edited the answer and added in a function that will take the value of the select, and redirect to the url.  Which is currently just a #.    You can edit that and put whatever action you need into there.

NB I have added in a CSS class "dropdown-toggle" to the select div.  So the change function can target that element alone.

Comment: very cool. I had done the same thing, but added it directly to the select itself. I'll try your way to see if it interacts with the other items more betterer. My last question is how to get the staff members to display once I've made the selection. The options all have data-category-slugs, which are supposed to then display the staff members attached to that particular slug. This is why the redirect values are #.